# Face builder equivalent

Tags: open-source, animation

Is there an open source software that does what Keen tools does? I can't afford the face builder and I really loved using it for a short time. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

facebuilder is for free in beta for blender. you can use it without paying anything..

You can also use facegen modeller (https://facegen.com/modeller.htm) to create a head from 2d images or for example something like http://www.makehumancommunity.org/ to create a custom head similar to your liking by hand.

But for perfect results and no hand work you got to pay or learn how to properly model and texture yourself.